# Mimicking Bootstrap's Webpage's Navbar (with Angular)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

## 1. The Problem

I'm trying to mimic [`Bootstrap`'s Webpage's Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/) but I'm having no success, despite having the same classes all around. I'm also using `Angular` and that got me wondering if that was related to something in the `TypeScript` framework and not with `Bootstrap` itself — that is the case for the dropdown button for example.

The main issue is that the `ul`s with the menu items and social icons are not forming different rows when the screen width is reduced.

For example, this is what I expected with my website:

[image]

And this is what I got instead:

[image]

## 2. The Code

I'm not using anything fancy in `Angular` at this point, just plain objects' properties (I've tried it with a `header` instead of a `nav` also):

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
  <a 
    class="navbar-brand mr-0 mr-md-2"
    routerLink="/">
      Logo
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-nav-scroll">
    <ul class="navbar-nav bd-navbar-nav flex-row">
      <li 
        class="nav-item" 
        *ngFor="let itemNavbar of itemsNavbar">
          <a 
            [routerLink]="itemNavbar['page']"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
            routerLinkActive="active" 
            class="nav-link">
              {{ itemNavbar[langNavbar] }}
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li 
      class="nav-item"
      *ngFor="let socialIcon of socialIcons">
        <a
          class="nav-link"
          href="{{ socialIcon.link }}">
            <i [ngClass]="socialIcon.icon"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you imported the css correctly into your angular project?

Comment: I think so... otherwise would the picture I shared be possible? In `angular.json`, I've added `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",` to `"styles"`. And that was after `npm install --save boostrap`.

Comment: The best way of checking this is to open a browser and then inspecting if the rules are applying. If they are, and the rules are from the css, then you're fine.

Comment: The only difference I could find is that the `CSS` for that `Bootstrap` page has some overrides. But, after copy-pasting them into my own project, nothing seemed to change.

Comment: From own experience, any style you enter lower on your stylesheet, towards the bottom, even if you have a duplicate style, one on the upper level and the duplicate lower placed, the lower style will overwrite the top style.  I would look out for that too.

Comment: Also, when you copy/ pasted into your own project, I assume you added '!important' to each style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boy, do I feel stupid for this...

After a lot of time tinkering with the subelements, the mistake was at the top all along. I had accidentally copy-pasted the `<nav>` element at the top from another page, and, thus, it lacked the `flex-column` and `flex-md-row` classes:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light flex-column flex-md-row bg-light">
```

Anyway, thank you very much for those who tried to help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, Philippe! Make you mark your own answer as the correct one for others to see :)

Comment: Thanks, but first I have to wait for 2 whole days before I can mark my own answer as the official/correct one.